# load jquery script in head section of specific magento cms page

Tags: jquery, magento

I'm trying to get a js script to load in my head section for two days now.
And it still doesnt work..
I'm building a cms page with a form bij which you can order some product samples (max 5)
at the en of the page there is a small contcat for m to submit the request

needed setup:
-intro text text
- a grid with pictures and checkboxes
- a contact form below to send the sample request

at this point i have tried almost all possible options.
- added  via custom page layout xml

```
    <reference name="head">
    <action method="addJs"><script>js/my.js</script></action>
    </reference>
```

- made a custom samplerequest.phtml and load that via 
  {{block type="core/template" template="page/kleurstalen.phtml"}}
- added the js true the page.xml etc etc.

this is the jquery code i want to load:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jq(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#kleurstalenform').submit(function() {
if( jQuery('input:checked').length == 0 ) {
alert('U heeft geen stofstallen geselecteerd');
return false;
}
});
jq(":checkbox").bind('click', function(){
if( jq('input:checked').length > 4 ) {
jq(this).attr('checked', false);
alert( 'U kunt maximaal 4 stofstalen bij ons aanvragen.' );
}
});
});
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

I have no clue why it doesn't work? maybe it is a scope issue?

Thanks for your advice!

Best

A

Answer (score 0):

You should have checked in the console (F12 in Chrome developer tools) as I am thinking you have done the right thing by adding the script my.js to the head block via the custom page layout.xml.  However, the js you've added will be full of errors, which is why it's not working.

You've got `jQuery`, `jq` and then you are setting the noConflict variable at the end using `$j`.

You are also including a js file via the `addJs` method, so there's no need to include opening and closing `<script>` tags in the file my.js. Try the script below and see if that gets you anywhere;

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function() {

    $j('#kleurstalenform').submit(function() {
        if( $j('input:checked').length == 0 ) {
            alert('U heeft geen stofstallen geselecteerd');
            return false;
        }
   });

    $j(":checkbox").bind('click', function(){
        if( $j('input:checked').length > 4 ) {
            $j(this).attr('checked', false);
            alert( 'U kunt maximaal 4 stofstalen bij ons aanvragen.' );
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add js file by using local.xml

in this file app/design/frontend/YOUR_THEME/default/layout/local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<default>
   <reference name="head">
     <action method="addItem">js/your_file.js</name></action>
   </reference>
</default>
```

and put your js file at this location app/design/frontend/YOUR_THEME/default/skin/js

Answer (score 0):

I've got the checkbox part of the js working!:)

i modified the script at your suggestion and added the code below to my page layout xml ..
(i also worked directly in a cms page instead of working with the custom block or .phtml)

Custom layout update XML:

```
    <reference name="head">
   <action method="addItem">
       <type>skin_js</type><name>js/kleurstalen.js</name>
   </action>
</reference>
```

Now the script works and allows only 4 samples to be checked, which is what i needed..

But..

The contact form in the page doesn't send the request
form validation is also needed, (so i have to look for some tutorials on this..)
I thought i could use the "default" varien scripts for this but upon now it won't work

on my sample request cms page i have added this to my  code

```
<div><form id="kleurstalenform" action="" method="POST">
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
<
var customForm = new VarienForm('kleurstalenform');>
// ]]></script>
```

i thought this could work with in combination with the js file for the checkbox maximum
But maybe the new varienForm part also needs some direction per xml?
I have no clue on what to add , to make it work..

Many thanks!

Best

A